# can't change order of a legend in R

Tags: r

I would like to do a LISA cluster.

Now I would like to change the order of the LISA Cluster in R

```
quadrant <- vector(mode="numeric",length=nrow(local))

# centers the variable of interest around its mean
m.qualification <- OA.Census$Qualification - mean(OA.Census$Qualification)     

# centers the local Moran's around the mean
m.local <- local[,1] - mean(local[,1])    

# significance threshold
signif <- 0.1 

# builds a data quadrant
quadrant[m.qualification >0 & m.local>0] <- 4  
quadrant[m.qualification <0 & m.local<0] <- 1      
quadrant[m.qualification <0 & m.local>0] <- 2
quadrant[m.qualification >0 & m.local<0] <- 3
quadrant[local[,5]>signif] <- 0   

# plot in r
brks <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
colors <- c("white","blue",rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.4),rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.4),"red")
plot(OA.Census,border="lightgray",col=colors[findInterval(quadrant,brks,all.inside=FALSE)])
box()
legend("bottomleft", legend = c("insignificant","low-low","low-high","high-low","high-high"),
       fill=colors,bty="n")
```

[image]

But I don't know how can I do that

I want high high at top and insignificant at last

since I can't share any data that was the only solution I found

Comment: Maybe you can reverse your legend names and colors using `rev`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
colors <-(c("white","blue",rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.4),rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.4),"red"))

legend("bottomleft", legend = rev(c("insignificant","low-low","low-high","high-low","high-high")),
       fill=rev(colors),bty="n")
```

This is the right code

Answer (score 0):

Just `rev`erse the `colors` and `legend` vectors:

```
colors <- rev(c("white","blue",rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.4),rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.4),"red"))

legend("bottomleft", legend = rev(c("insignificant","low-low","low-high","high-low","high-high")),
       fill=colors,bty="n")
```

Comment: and fill=rev(colors)

Comment: colors <- rev() is not necessary